# Does qStableSort preserve order of equivalent elements?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, containers

Suppose I have a [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html) of 100 `MyItem` objects inserted in a certain order. Every `MyItem` has an associated `timestamp` and some property `p`, which is not guaranteed to be unique.

```
struct MyItem {
    enum MyProperty { ONE, TWO, THREE };

    double timestamp;   //unique
    MyProperty p;       //non-unique

    bool operator<(const MyItem& other) const {
        return p < other.p;
    }
};
```

Supposing I added my 100 objects in chronological order, if I were to run [qStableSort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qStableSort-3) on that container (thereby sorting by `p`), do I have a guarantee that for a given value of `p` that they are still in chronological order?

Comment: I don't actually know anything at all about `qStableSort`, but I thought that's what the `stable` part of any `stable sort` meant - order of equivalent elements is maintained. [Wikipedia Stable Sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts)

Comment: I think you mean "not guaranteed to be unique" :). Anyway, that is the definition of what "stable" means in "stable sort".

Comment: @dwanderson I suppose that's exactly my question. The function description just says that it's "stable" without defining the term.

Comment: Thanks both of you. When I initially made the switch from [qSort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qSort) to [qStableSort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qStableSort-3) it was because qSort crashed my program and qStableSort did not, so I thought it was an indication of runtime stability, not order stability.

Comment: @Phlucious gotcha. From everything I've ever seen, it means the order is maintained from the original list, where two elements compare equal. So it ought to maintain chronological order if-and-only-if those items that compare equal were inserted into the array in chronological order (which sounds pretty reasonable, but just trying to be precise here).

Comment: From the documentation the order is preserved on equal items: "Sorts the items in range [begin, end) in ascending order using a stable sorting algorithm.

If neither of the two items is "less than" the other, the items are taken to be equal. The item that appeared before the other in the original container will still appear first after the sort. This property is often useful when sorting user-visible data."

Comment: *because qSort crashed my program and qStableSort did not* this is a symptom of having a comparison function violating [Strict Weak Ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

Comment: @peppe I don't follow. How does the < operator violate Strict Weak Ordering as shown? It's true when a.p < b.p, false when a.p > b.p, and false when a.p == b.p.

Comment: The one above does not violate it, but I thought that was some simplified code. The above should definitely not crash when fed into `qSort` / `std::sort`, if it does, `valgrind` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts

> Stable sorting algorithms maintain the relative order of records with equal keys (i.e. values). That is, a sorting algorithm is stable if whenever there are two records R and S with the same key and with R appearing before S in the original list, R will appear before S in the sorted list.

Therefore the keyword *stable* in `qStableSort` is referring exactly to what you're asking for.

Note however, that `qStableSort` is [obsoleted in Qt 5.5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html#qStableSort)

> Use std::stable_sort instead.
>
> Sorts the items in range [begin, end) in ascending order using a stable sorting algorithm.
>
> If neither of the two items is "less than" the other, the items are taken to be equal. The item that appeared before the other in the original container will still appear first after the sort. This property is often useful when sorting user-visible data.

As per the Qt documentation, you should prefer to use [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)

Comment: I can't find any documentation explaining why std::stable_sort would be preferred. Is there any?

Comment: @Phlucious: It's explained in the mail I wrote announcing the change http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-September/013122.html , as well as in the 5.2.0 changelog: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.2.0

Comment: @peppe Great link! The docs say that it was deprecated in 5.5, so I didn't look as far back as 5.2.0.

Comment: Well it just says it's deprecated. I don't think it says *when* it was (not sure if that piece of information is possibly useful for someone...). See also https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qtalgorithms.html#qt-and-the-stl-algorithms